# Running repeated task from a foreground service

Tags: java, android, service, threadpool

I want to run repeated task 3 times only from a foreground service.
I tried to use `ScheduledExecutorService`

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
            .newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    counter = 0;
    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         if (counter<3) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Do something useful");
         }
          else {
            scheduler.shutdownNow()
         }
       }
      }
    }, 2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But im not sure if it's the right way to go with.
This repeated task will run only 3 times and will stop after that.
AlarmManager is another option but sounds to me like an overkill for this short period task.

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Hi @mynavy , your task repeated 3 times and you shutdown the scheduler  `scheduler.shutdownNow()`. So you don't want to stop the repeated task ?

Comment: Hi @RustFisher , yeah i want to stop the repeated task after 3 times , thats why im not sure about using it this way

Comment: It depends on you needs  :)  I think it is a good way for now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , what alternatives do you prefer for running short repeated tasks in a background service ?

Comment: I think Timer and scheduler are both good.